# Error 'invalid syntax' when trying to run elif

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

This might be a really obvious question, but I'm just starting out with Python, and received a syntax error in relation to the second elif statement in this code:

```
    if userInput == 'sleep':
        print('Goodnight... zzzzz')
        day += 1
        time = 'day'
        print('Goodmorning!')
    elif userInput == 'eat':
        if 'bread' in inventory:
            print('You have eaten 1x bread from your inventory. This has'
            ' restored your hunger by 5, and your health by 5. Your'
            ' hunger is now {}, and your health is {}.'.format(playerHunger + 5, playerHealth + 5)
    elif userInput == 'pick up':
        pickUpInput = input('What would you like to pick up?')
    if room == 1:
        if pickUpInput in r1Contents:
            print('1x {} added to inventory.'.format(pickUpInput))
            r1Contents.remove(pickUpInput)
            inventory.append(pickUpInput)
```

The error is

```
  File "foo.py", line 11
    elif userInput == 'pick up':
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Sorry it's long, but it's as little as possible to explain my problem. I've checked the indents multiple times and dedented and re-indented again and again, so I'm pretty certain it's not that, but if I've made a stupid mistake and it is, sorry!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you share the exact text of the error?

Comment: 'syntax error' and the 'e' of the second elif is highlighted in red

Comment: I added the error message to your question to demonstrate how useful it is to show the problem in the question.

Comment: You have a second problem with the indentation of an "if" but I may have accidentally injected that when I edited the question. I will take a look.

Comment: Yep, that was me injecting a bug by failing to dedent the final `if`

Comment: You're missing a closing parentheses on the print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the print in the line above the `elif` is missing its closing parenthesis. Change it to

```
print('You have eaten 1x bread from your inventory. This has'
        ' restored your hunger by 5, and your health by 5. Your'
        ' hunger is now {}, and your health is {}.'.format(playerHunger =+ 5, playerHealth =+ 5))
```

This kind of thing can be easier to spot if you try to keep your code from going off the right hand side

```
print('You have eaten 1x bread from your inventory. This has'
        ' restored your hunger by 5, and your health by 5. Your'
        ' hunger is now {}, and your health is {}.'.format(
    playerHunger =+ 5, playerHealth =+ 5))
```

or if you put the string in a separate variable

```
msg = ('You have eaten 1x bread from your inventory. This has'
       ' restored your hunger by 5, and your health by 5. Your'
       ' hunger is now {}, and your health is {}.')
print(msg.format(playerHunger =+ 5, playerHealth =+ 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Change these line to the same indent level:

```py
    elif userInput == 'pick up':
        pickUpInput = input('What would you like to pick up?')
        if room == 1:
            if pickUpInput in r1Contents:
                print('1x {} added to inventory.'.format(pickUpInput))
                r1Contents.remove(pickUpInput)
                inventory.append(pickUpInput)
```

Also, don't use increments here (`+=`), as they would return None but not the value. Increment the values first, and use them just as variables.
The increment code is incorrect, change `=+` to `+=`.

```py
playerHunger += 5
playerHealth += 5
...
' hunger is now {}, and your health is {}.'.format(playerHunger, playerHealth)
```

Comment: That's not the only issue.

Comment: All of those lines? Wouldn't that remove the nested indent and therefore the effects thereof?

Comment: Just added more fixes